# Custom Local Font is not working after deploying to the server in VUE

Tags: vue.js, server, fonts

I have worked with Vue CLI 3 project and used a custom local fonts in this project. These custom fonts are working fine on local but after building to the server it is not working. 
Is this something related to my Vue.config.js file?

This is my vue.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/', // Base directory for dev
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "assets/fonts/[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, you need this custom file loading for fonts when using `vue-cli 3`? It should also work without it because it is already built into `vue-cli`.

Comment: Yeah, but actually I am using vue-cli 3, but it is not working after deploying to now server.

Comment: How do they not work on your server? Can they not be loaded? Is there any error in the devtools console?

Comment: Yeah, there is no error. I am sure you know the NOW server. I think this issue is coming from the webpack config. Is this what you can give me advice?

Comment: Do you actually import the font files anywhere? You should somewhere import a [tag:css] file with an `@font-face` statement with a `src` pointing to your font files. Then, they should be loaded (see the network tab in the Chrome devtools). To see, if a specific element uses the correct font file, you can select a specific element in the Chrome devtools and in the `computed` section at the bottom, you can see the source of the font (`Rendered font`).